# Deducing type from template class conversion operator

Tags: c++, type-deduction

I'm debugging an issue in a large C++ codebase where an attribute of a struct is occasionally being changed to a bad value. Unfortunately, the attribute is public and is accessed or changed in hundreds of places, so simply adding a breakpoint on a mutator is not possible. Also, I don't know the *instance* of the struct, so adding an address watchpoint wouldn't help.

Instrumenting the code would be a major job. However, a colleague helpfully suggested creating a proxy class which could wrap the existing type in the struct declaration. For example, instead of using `MyType _type` I would replace this with `ChangeProxy<MyType> _type` in the struct and the application should compile and work with the proxy taking the place of the direct type in the same manner as, for example, a smart pointer.

However, when I build an example, the implicit conversion operation in the template class doesn't appear to get invoked in type deduction. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyType {
    long _n = 0;

    public:
        MyType() {}
        MyType(const long n) : _n{n} {}
        MyType& operator=(const long n) { _n = n; return *this; }
        bool isZero() const { return _n != 0; }
};

template <class T>
class ChangeProxy {
    public:
        ChangeProxy() {}
        ChangeProxy(const T& t) : _t{t} {}
        ChangeProxy(const T&& t) : _t{std::move(t)} {}
        ChangeProxy& operator=(const T& t) {onChange(t); _t = t; return *this;}
        ChangeProxy& operator=(const T&& t) {onChange(t); _t = std::move(t); return *this;}
        operator T() {return _t;}
    private:
        T _t;
        void onChange(const T& newVal) { /* something here to notify me of changes */ };
};

struct MyStruct {
    // MyType _type;              // this works ...
    ChangeProxy<MyType> _type;    // .. but this doesn't
};

int main() {

    MyStruct i;
    std::cout << "i._type.isZero() : " << std::boolalpha << i._type.isZero() << std::endl;
    i._type = 1;
    std::cout << "i._type.isZero() : " << std::boolalpha << i._type.isZero() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, when I build this I get the following errors:

```
proxy-variable~test.cpp:35:73: error: ‘class ChangeProxy<MyType>’ has no member named ‘isZero’
   35 |         std::cout << "i._type.isZero() : " << std::boolalpha << i._type.isZero() << std::endl;
      |                                                                         ^~~~~~
proxy-variable~test.cpp:37:73: error: ‘class ChangeProxy<MyType>’ has no member named ‘isZero’
   37 |         std::cout << "i._type.isZero() : " << std::boolalpha << i._type.isZero() << std::endl;
      |                                                                         ^~~~~~
```

So it seems that the compiler isn't deducing that it can cast a `ChangeProxy<MyType>` to a `MyType`. What have I done wrong here?

Comment: Wait a second – you have defined an `operator=` anyway – why not directly modify that one, e. g. by adding logging there? You could enable that *conditionally* (`#ifdef LOG_VALUE_CHANGES /* ... */ #endif`), that appears simpler to me...

Comment: How is the bad value determined? Is it possible to have run-time tests to catch the value under certain circumstances?

Comment: Your `operator T` might possibly rather return a reference instead of a copy.

Comment: I suppose inheritance is out of the question.

Comment: As it is for debugging, you can add `isZero()` method to your wrapper (which forward to the wrapped type).

Comment: Inheritance is certainly an option, but unfortunately, it would work best on a small class with a limited interface which isn't the case here. The class I'm dealing with is quite large so I potentially have to replicate (wrap) most of the interface, and remember if I get the interface wrong it may simply use the base function silently. If I had an interface (virtual base) to work with, that might make things easier, but I don't. Replicating the class in full is not the worst thing in the world, but still a lot of manual effort and risk that I'd rather avoid.

Comment: @Component10 Other way around. I'm not talking about your types inheriting form ChangeProxy; I'm talking about ChanegProxy<T> inheriting from T. ChangeProxy has one member var, a T, so it is the most-trivial of composites. Inheriting, throwing out `_t`, and carefully crafting the constructions and operators may suffice. It would seem a possible alternative approach to your dilemma. Just a thought volley.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks, yes, that's how I was imagining it i.e `template <class T> class ChangeProxy : public T {`

Answer (score 4):

The context here doesn't let the compiler try out implicit conversions. Calling a member function on some object never does. You can force this by e.g.

```
std::cout << "i._type.isZero() : " << std::boolalpha <<
         static_cast<MyType>(i._type).isZero() << '\n';
//       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Here, enforce conversion
```

Another option would be:

```
MyStruct i;
const MyType& underlying = i._type; // Again, request conversion manually
std::cout << underlying.isZero() << '\n';
```

Comment: Thanks, though neither of these are really acceptable as they require changes to the  code in hundreds of places and that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Yeah that doesn't sound doable. If the interface of the type you intend to wrap isn't too tedious/large/complicated, you could duplicate the interface and forward everything to the wrapped type.

Comment: Yep, unfortunately it is! That said though, I had thought of inheritance rather than aggregation, and also it's only really the constructors/mutators that I'm interested in. The non-const portion of the interface is generally a smaller subset compared to the const part, so may be worth looking at still.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is invoking a method on the class `ChangeProxy<MyType>` which indeed doesn't have any method `isZero()` defined on it, hence the compilation error. You could probably add something like

```
T const& operator()() const {return _t;}
```

And then call it using

```
i._type().isZero()
```

Comment: Such an operator is already there (but returning copies...) – problem rather is that it isn't called implicitly.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem: If I have to change every instance of `i._type` to `i._type()` (hundreds, and there are other unconnected `_type` attributes so I can't easily automate), then I may as well just make it private and add `type()` accessor and mutator. Manually doing this is days of work that can't really be justified.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the wrapped `i._type.isZero()` can never work is that implicit conversions of the `i._type` object aren't considered for direct method calls, and you can't overload `operator.` like you can `operator->`.

It's nothing to do with type deduction, there's simply no mechanism in the language to do what you want.

Luckily, you're solving the wrong problem anyway.

> ... a colleague helpfully suggested creating a proxy class which could wrap the existing type in the struct declaration

Hmm, you didn't mention that [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/436925/39877) - or am I a colleague now?

> an attribute of a struct is occasionally being changed to a bad value

**Which** attribute? Be specific!

In your code, you're treating the `MyType` instance as the problematic attribute. However, the only state in `MyType` is its `long _n` member.

Writing

```
class MyType {
    ChangeProxy<long> _n = 0;
```

which is what I actually suggested when I referred to wrapping *built-in types*, avoids this problem entirely. You may of course need `operator!=` to make `isZero` work, but that's a normally overloadable operator.

Oddly the code in your question doesn't permit any mutation of `_n` anyway, so it's unclear how it can be getting a bad value. However, I assume this is just an artefact of a simplified example.

Comment: Yes, this is a much simplified example and in retrospect does not clarify a few things - particularly in relation to whether the attribute I want to wrap in a built-in or a complex type. The class I'm dealing with is significantly bigger and contains more than a simple int. Points taken, thanks. Just to be clear, a work colleague had suggested this approach after I asked on SE. This lead me to ask here after I couldn't get the wrapper to work, but before I saw your answer on SE.

Comment: I'm sure the class you're working with contains more than a simple int - the question is what actual members of that are getting corrupted. If you can't be clearer about the semantics you need and what is actually happening, I don't see how anyone can help you.